# Measuring the distance between two probability measures using quantile functions?

Tags: distributions, quantiles, distance, metric

There are many metrics on the space of probability measures on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B)$.

Most of the famous metrics use the distribution functions associated with the probability measures to compute their distance. But some laws do not have an explicit form of distribution function, but they do have a nice quantile function. Are there any famous metric on the space of probability measures on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B)$ (you can add $L^p$ regularity if needed) that are based on quantile functions instead of distribution functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wasserstein-2 metric for univariate probability measures can be formulated in terms of quantile functions. If $P_1$ and $P_2$ are probability measures with quantile functions $q_1$ and $q_2$, the squared Wasserstein distance between them is
$$ W^2(P_1,P_2) = \int_0^1 (q_1(u)-q_2(u))^2du. $$
For a proof, see Peterson and Muller, "Wasserstein covariance for multiple random densities".

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** to reflect @dave's observation:

For continuous probability distributions, defined on a connected set in $\mathbf R$ (eg. an interval $[a,b]$, $\mathbf R$ or one of the half lines $\mathbf R_{\leq 0}, \, \mathbf R_{\geq 0}$) we can show that pointwise convergence of the quantile function is equivalent to convergence in distribution.

To see this we note:

- For continuous distributions, the quantile function $Q$ is the inverse of the CDF $F$.
- $Q$ and $F$ are monotonic increasing functions.
- Connectedness of the domain (support) of the distribution ensures the functions are strictly monotonic - and hence bijective.

Together these are sufficient conditions for pointwise convergence of a sequence $Q_n \rightarrow Q$ to imply pointwise convergence of their inverses (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/291354)), $F_n \rightarrow F$, which is the definition of convergence in distribution.

Comment: You have to be a bit careful about defining the inverse, since a continuous CDF can be flat on an interval. Caseload and Berger discuss this when they do the probability integral transform.

Comment: Hi @dave - My comment is for continuous distributions, which I understood (assumed?!) have strictly increasing CDFs. Wouldn't a flat interval on a CDF imply a discontinuity in the support of the distribution (though the CDF itself is still continuous). If so - I think my proof stands as it is? If I've misunderstood - perhaps an example of what you're getting at would help?

Comment: Example: uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ and $(2,3)$. Sketch the CDF. It will angle up, flatten out, and then angle up again before flattening out.

Comment: Aha - yes good point. So the issue here then is that the domain is not connected. So if I add the condition that the support of the distribution is connected would you agree? So in practice - the support is an interval $[a,b]$, $\mathbf R$ or one of the half lines of positive/negative reals.

Comment: If your support isn’t all of $\mathbb{R}$, how would you handle the long part of CDF that’s $0$ or $1?$

Comment: By defining the CDF as a function on the interval. The quantile function is only defined on $[0,1]$; it is perfectly reasonable to consider its inverse only on the domain of possible values.